# How to convert switch state into integer in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswitch

I am using five switches for handling different types of notifications. To remember the state of the switch, I am thinking of converting state of five switches into an integer. For example, if my switches status is as follow, 01010 then the integer should be 10. Please help me how to achieve this.

Comment: It's very easy --- binary to decimal conversion

Comment: Sorry question  not clear..

Comment: 01010 means, first switch is off, second is on, third is off, fourth on and fifth of again. I want this boolean values to be converted to binary and then integer.

Comment: I am using five switches, which will be different states at different times. I want to remember the status when I come back to the screen. So I want the states to be converted to binary values and that to a decimal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*(Why bother encoding your 5 switch values into a single integer? Storing 5 Booleans is not hard. That said the question is how to do it...)*

**Important aside: BOOL values are not 0 and 1**

Objective-C is a superset of C, and in the original C there was no Boolean type - instead it just used an integer type with the interpretation that 0 was false and *anything else* was true.

Objective-C defines `BOOL` as a `signed char`, that is an 8-bit signed integer type (as characters are just an integer type in C). So in Objective-C 0 is false, and -128..-1, 1..127 are all true. `NO` is defined as `0` and `YES` as `1`, but various operations may result in other values.

To get a `0` or `1` from a `BOOL` `b` you can use the conditional operator:

```
b ? 1 : 0
```

However the built in logical operators *by definition* will always return `0` or `1` and never any of the other possible values. The `!` operator is logical not, and two not's get you back to where you started so:

```
!!b
```

will also give you a `0` or `1`.

In any code that takes a `BOOL` and tries to use it as a `0` or `1` you should really use one of the above (or an equivalent).

**One way to solve it: using strings**

Your question has been interpreted as using a string as an intermediary during the encoding. First assume the class has your five buttons stored in an instance variable as a simple array (it will allow us to loop):

```
const int kSWITCH_COUNT = 5; // let's not hard code it everywhere

@implemention MyClass
{
   Switch *switches[kSWITCH_COUNT];
}
```

then the string method goes something like:

```
- (void) stringMethod
{
   NSMutableString *binarystring = NSMutableString.new;
   // build up the string one value at a time, note the !! so we only get 0 or 1 values
   for (int ix = 0; ix < kSWITCH_COUNT; ix++)
      [binarystring appendFormat:@"%d", !!switches[ix].isOn];

   long decimalValue = strtol([binarystring  UTF8String], NULL, 2);
   NSLog(@"Encoded: 0x%lx", decimalValue);
}
```

This method works, but it is rather a circuitous way of getting to the result - you have 5 integer (Boolean) values and you want to combine them into an integer, why involve strings?

**A better way to solve it: using integers**

(Objective-)C provides bitwise operators to do shifts, or, and, etc. operations which treat integer types as an ordered collection of bits - which is what they are on a computer.

The `<<` operator shifts left, e.g. `0x1 << 1` produces `0x2`, i.e. `<< 1` is equivalent to multiplication by 2. The `|` operator is bitwise or, e.g. 0x1 << 1 | 1`produces`0x3`. The answer to your question now follows easily:

```
- (void) shiftMethod
{
   unsigned int encoded = 0;

   for (int ix = 0; ix < kSWITCH_COUNT; ix++)
      encoded = (encoded << 1) | !!switches[ix].isOn;

   NSLog(@"Encoded: 0x%x", encoded);
}
```

If you don't like shifts and ors you can use multiplication and addition:

```
     encoded = encoded * 2 + !!switches[ix].isOn;
```

The above solves the problem directly, no converting to/from intermediate strings. It happens to be a lot faster as well, but in the overall scheme of an application neither approach is probably going to take a significant proportion of the execution time and you shouldn't select based on that.

**A Third Way**

If you are going to wish to set/get the individual bits of an integer a lot you can use `struct` types with bit-field widths. These let you set/get the bits of an integer directly - no shifting etc. required - and you may find them useful, but they are rather "low level". Any good book on C will show you how to use these.

HTH

Answer (score 3):

1. At first extract each switch value and store it in a single string
2. Now convert the string to decimal /integer value like this:-

---

```
 NSString * binarystring = @"01010";
 long decimalValue = strtol([binarystring  UTF8String], NULL, 2);
 NSLog(@"%ld", decimalValue );
```

**Edit**

Get all switch control value in single string:-

```
NSString *binarystring = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i%i%i%i%i",self.switch1.isOn,self.switch2.isOn,self.switch3.isOn,self.switch4.isOn,self.switch5.isOn];
```

Comment: Vizllx thanx, can u please help me how to store different switch values in a single string.

Comment: Sorry for that, I actually forgot. I am having 5 diff switches. Please help me storing switch states in string (binary)

Comment: @Naveen for example, NSString *binaryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d%d%d%d", switch1.isOn, switch2.isOn ,switch3.isOn ,switch4.isOn , switch5.isOn];

Comment: @curious- You are faster than me ;)